# How to match xpath for id element that changes each time page loads?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have these 2 xpath that are different each time I load a webpage.

The xpaths were recorded by Selenium-IDE and always have `mainForm_view` within the id string and the text before and after this always changes.

```
xpath=//input[@id='abc_hyd_wuu2_8333nd_mainForm_view_jjd_uueue2_jjd_11_jkdhd']
xpath=//div[@id='abc_hyd_wuu2_8333nd_mainForm_view_kcjjcs_sjsjs_jjdj_994_kkk']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a[1]/h2
```

I've tried to locate the id like below but doesn't work.

```
xpath=//input[contains(@id,'mainForm_view')]
xpath=//div[contains(@id,'mainForm_view')]
```

Which would be the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've tried with CSS selector like below but it seems is taking another `id` that is within an `input` element

```
document.querySelector("input[id*='mainForm_view']").id
```

Examining the html code I see that the `id` I need is related with a unique `class`. The code is like below:

```
  <div class="Class_p2">
     <div class="Class_p3" style="...">
        <input name="8333nd$mainForm$view$jjd$uueue2" type="text" class="class a1 n1-Control" value="xyz" id="8333nd_mainForm_view_jjd_uueue2" disabled="disabled" style="..">
     </div>
     <input name="8333nd$mainForm$view$ttyi" type="text" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
```

I've tried the following Javascript code in Chrome console but it doesn't work

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class a1 n1-Control").id
```

How would be to get the `id=8333nd_mainForm_view_jjd_uueue2` that is related with `Class=class a1 n1-Control`?

**UPDATE2**

I was finally able to do it with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class a1 n1-Control")[0].id
```

Thanks for all the help and time.

Comment: can you try this instead? //div[@id[contains(.,'mainForm_view')]]

Comment: Your code looks correct given the information you have given us.

Comment: @JimGrigoryan Thanks for the info. May you see my Update in original post. Still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MichaelKay May you see my Update in original post. Still doesn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: @EdBangga Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried like you said, but stil doesn't work for me. May you see my Update in original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can write **css selector** as :

```
input[id*='mainForm_view']
```

for div it'd be :

```
div[id*='mainForm_view']
```

Asterisk is to match the sub string part.

Note that if any id contains **mainForm_view** that will also be selected, so better to check in developers tool before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks the help. I've tried your suggestion about to use CSS selector, but is taking id from another input element. May you see my Update in original post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding some other element for which xpath/css locator remains same and then try to reach to this element by traversing from there. You can use parent, ancestor, preceding-sibling, following-sibling keywords in order to traverse. Hope it helps :)